# Facebook: What is the correct way to post a checkin and view checked in friends using the latest API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

`/me/checkins` is deprecated and no longer works however with the latest API `me/feed` specifying the place its impossible to post a checkin that can be read back using this query:

```
me/friends?fields=checkins.limit(1).fields(from,message,place.fields(id,name,location,likes,website,phone,description,checkins),tags)
```

This graph API will only show checkins created using the old API:

```
/me/checkins
```

What is the correct way of specifying a checkin when posting to me/feed and viewing your friends checkins?

So far the only solution for retrieving checked in friends details that I can get to work is:

```
SELECT source_id, created_time, message, attachment, message_tags, place FROM stream WHERE (source_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())) AND (with_location=1) AND (created_time>????)
```

However, I think its unacceptable because it will often return more data than necessary. There doesn't seem to be a way using FQL to limit the query to return only the first record for each source_id

Comment: So far I think the only way to view friends checkins is to get the friends list and for each friend get the last post in their feed that has a place set which is much more complicated than the single query for checked in friends that worked previously.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, you started your question stating `/me/checkins` is deprecated so why would you query from it here as a field expansion

`me/friends?fields=checkins.limit(1).fields(from,message,place.fields(id,name,location,likes,website,phone,description,checkins),tags)`

Use location instead.

> When retrieving location information via the /locations connection on the User object, or via the location_post FQL table, return Checkin objects prior to February 20, 2011 along with Statuses when you request the user_status permission (newer Checkins are automatically included). Without this migration enabled, you'll have to request user_checkins separately to retrieve these older Checkins.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/status_checkin_perm_migration_migration/

> The behavior of Checkins is affected by the "Include Checkins with Statuses" migration setting.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

Comment: The Facebook docs say that /me/checkins is deprecated and instead we should post a status update to /me/feed specifying a place. This works in itself but so far it does not seem straight forward to view the last checkin (feed update with place) for all your friends.